# Undefined function bool_and in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the code below:

```
df_logical = df_parcial.groupBy("customer_id", "person_id").agg(
when(expr("bool_and(is_online_store)"), "Online")
.when(expr("bool_and(!is_online_store)"), "Offline")
.when(expr("bool_and(is_online_store)").isNull(), None)
.otherwise("Hybrid").alias("type_person"))
```

And the rules I have are as follows:

- If PersonId count(column) has 1 or + Trues and None False then Online
- If PersonId count(column) has 1 or + False and None True then offline
- If the PersonId count(column) has at least 1 False AND 1 True then Hybrid

But when I went to upload the code to production, the following error appears:

> Undefined function: 'bool_and'. This function is neither a registered
> temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database
> 'default'.; line 1 pos 0

How can I get around this error?

Table original:

| customer | PersonId | is_online_store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| afabd2d2 | 4 | true |
| afabd2d2 | 8 | true |
| afabd2d2 | 3 | true |
| afabd2d2 | 2 | false |
| afabd2d2 | 4 | false |

Table as it should be:

| customer | PersonId | type_person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| afabd2d2 | 4 | Hybrid |
| afabd2d2 | 8 | Online |
| afabd2d2 | 3 | Online |
| afabd2d2 | 2 | Offline |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because [`bool_and`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#bool_and) function only is available since Spark 3. You can achieve the same using conditional count like this:

```
df_logical = df_parcial.groupBy("customer", "PersonId").agg(
    F.when(
        F.count(F.when(F.col("is_online_store") == "true", 1)) == F.count("*"), "Online"
    ).when(
        F.count(F.when(F.col("is_online_store") == "false", 1)) == F.count("*"), "Offline"
    ).otherwise("Hybrid").alias("New_Column")
)
```

Comment: .when(expr("bool_and(is_online_store)").isNull(), None) and this?

Comment: @CarolineLeite you can't use `bool_and` function if you have spark version under 3